# Do White Walkers and wights see differently from ordinary humans?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

When a human turns into a White Walker or wight, their eyes turn bright blue. Is their vision altered as well? Do they see things better / worse / differently from unturned living humans?

Comment: There is literally no mention (both in the books, or in the show) about the visual capabilities of the Wights/Others/White Walkers.

Comment: They also don't seem to be affected negatively either. The only thing is that potentially, they can see better at night, but that's a guess.

Comment: @Möoz I was hoping it could shed a bit of light on Arya's Incredibly Successful Attack, but couldn't find anything either.

Comment: I mean, humans sometimes have bright blue eyes and can see perfectly well.

Comment: A change in eye color by itself has no effect on vision. Cats and other animals with night vision have reflective retinas, but this doesn't seem to be the case with White Walkers. They might have some kind of magical night vision, though.

Comment: @Adamant I'm sorry, I find that logic glib at best. I think that a much more honest way to address this is to recognize that a White Walker is not simply a blue-eyed human, and that their eyes likely become blue for a reason very different from natural eye pigmentation.

Comment: Well, sure, but if blue eyed people see fine in real life, then why would you expect White Walkers to have visual issues or differences?

Comment: @Adamant Well, because if the process is different, then the outcome is likely to be different.  Our eyes have evolved in such a way that natural pigmentation is not an important factor in vision.  This is not necessarily true for whatever process turns them blue in the transition from human to White Walker or wight.

Comment: to answer the question about arya's attack: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211164/94909

Comment: @Termatinator I remember that post very well. While it is a well thought-out opinion, it is nonetheless an opinion. The Night King may be arrogant, but he is also almost certainly far, far superior to Arya in a fight, considering that she had only been doing this for a few years. The Night King's arrogance is likely warranted. I could see him letting her get close, but I have trouble buying him letting her actually hit him, unless he *didn't notice* her switch the dagger. In which case eyesight matters.

Comment: @MishaR he must've noticed that as you can see him move his eyes while the dagger is falling

Comment: @Termatinator Maybe, but if his eyesight were good enough for him to know exactly what happened, then that makes the other answer less plausible too. I think that, for the most part, I just have trouble with the idea that the resolution of the whole conflict depended on Arya's awesome battle trick. Not to mention that the end of the main conflict of the series should depend on a well-established fault of the Night King, and arrogance simply hasn't been that important an aspect of his character. He did a couple of vaguely arrogant things, but mainly he was just evil.