# How did Arya avoid White Walkers and wights at the end of Season 8 Episode 3?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In 8x03, at the end of the episode, Arya

> jumps to the Night King and she has an opportunity to kill him.

But I don't understand how she can avoid all the wights and the White Walkers, because there are hundreds of them and they were looking at the same point, at Bran.

> The Night King was in font of Bran, so...

I don't understand how she can do it.

Comment: The duplicate asks about it from a different perspective but the answers are the same.

Comment: i try to found it, but i dont see anything before asking. Where I can see the original question, please? Thanks! :)

Comment: It's [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211164/58193) but note that as the question is closed you can see it at the top of the page on the _"This question already has an answer here:"_ banner.